# How to split the pairwise matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix of the following format

```
      gene ids  A-B   A-C  A-D  B-C  B-D C-D

      GENE1     0     0    1    1    1   0
      GENE2     1     0    1    1    1   1
      GENE3     1     0    0    0    1   1
      GENE4     0     1    0    0    0   0
```

and would like to split it as follows:The diagonal values will be empty because the above matrix is a pairwise comparison.

```
       Gene1
           A  B   C  D sum   
       A   -  0   0  1  1
       B   0  -   1  1  2
       C   0  1   -  0  1
       D   1  1   0  -  2

      Gene2
           A  B   C  D  sum
       A   -  1   0  1   2
       B   1  -   1  1   3
       C   0  1   -  1   2
       D   1  1   1  -   3

      Gene3
           A  B   C  D  sum
       A   -  1   0  0   1
       B   1  -   0  1   2
       C   0  0   -  1   1
       D   0  1   1  -   2

       Gene4
           A  B   C  D  sum
       A   -  0   1  0   1 
       B   0  -   0  0   0
       C   1  0   -  0   1
       D   0  0   0  -   0
```

This is only a subset of the data and I have more than  1000 genes to split in a similar way. I tried filling  the upper triangle with the transpose of the lower but was not successful when doing the same for many genes.  After splitting the whole matrix into different submatrices, I would like to sum row-wise and obtain a plot for the same for each gene..

The solution provided below does not work for more number comparisons:

For eg:

```
                  DF <- read.table(text="gene_ids  A-B A-C A-D A-E B-C  B-D B-E C-D C-E D-E
                  GENE1     0     0    1    1    1   0  1  0  1 1
                  GENE2     1     0    1    1    1   1  0  1  1 0
                  GENE3     1     0    0    0    1   1  0  1  0 1  
                   GENE4     0     1    0    0    0   0  1  1  1 0 
                  GENE5     1     1    0    0    0   0  0  1  1 1
                  GENE6    0     1    1   0    0   1  0  0  0 0",   header=TRUE)
```

Using the provided solution gives

```
                     :[[1]]
                     A  B  C  D  E sum
                   A NA  0  0  1  1   2
                   B  0 NA  1  1  0   2
                   C  0  1 NA  0  1   2
                   D  1  0  0 NA  1   2
                   E  1  1  1  1 NA   4
```

In RowB , column D the value is not what it should be ( it must be zero) and the Matrix is no longer symmetrical...so in most genes there are errors in the end !

Comment: I assume, the columns are always ordered like in your question?

Comment: Actually the columns are not ordered the same way and tends to change

Comment: Well, then just order the columns (except the first) alphabetically according to colnames prior to running the loop.

Comment: Fixed it again. Should work now as expected.

Comment: @Roland : Works perfectly !

Comment: Glad that you are happy with it. However, I would like to point out that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. The idea is that you learn from the answers and become able to adjust them as needed. Meaning you should have been able to fix the (regrettable) mistake yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="gene_ids  A-B A-C A-D A-E B-C  B-D B-E C-D C-E D-E
                  GENE1     0     0    1    1    1   0  1  0  1 1
                  GENE2     1     0    1    1    1   1  0  1  1 0
                 GENE3     1     0    0    0    1   1  0  1  0 1  
                 GENE4     0     1    0    0    0   0  1  1  1 0 
                 GENE5     1     1    0    0    0   0  0  1  1 1
                 GENE6    0     1    1   0    0   1  0  0  0 0",   header=TRUE)

m_temp <- matrix(NA,ncol=5,nrow=5)
up <- upper.tri(m_temp)
lo <- lower.tri(m_temp)

lapply(seq_len(nrow(DF)), function(i, res) {
  tmpnames <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(names(unlist(DF[i, -1])),"\\."))
  #possibly you need to adjust the seperator here

  rownames(res) <- c(tmpnames[1,1],tmpnames[tmpnames[,1]==tmpnames[1,1],2])
  res[lo] <- unlist(DF[i, -1])
  res[up] <- t(res)[up]
  res <- cbind(res, rowSums(res, na.rm = TRUE))
  colnames(res) <- c(rownames(res),"sum")
  res
}, res = m_temp)

# [[1]]
#    A  B  C  D  E sum
# A NA  0  0  1  1   2
# B  0 NA  1  0  1   2
# C  0  1 NA  0  1   2
# D  1  0  0 NA  1   2
# E  1  1  1  1 NA   4
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to include the header names like [,A] [,B] [,C] instead of [,1][,2] [,3] ????

Comment: @ Roland : But it does not seem to work once I include some more comparisons: For instance, I tried with this dataDF <- read.table(text="gene_ids  A-B A-C A-D A-E B-C  B-D B-E C-D C-E 
GENE1     0     0    1    1    1   0  1  0  1
GENE2     1     0    1    1    1   1  0  1  1
GENE3     1     0    0    0    1   1  0  1  0  
GENE4     0     1    0    0    0   0  1  1  1
GENE5     1     1    0    0    0   0  0  1  1
GENE6    0     1    1   0    0   1  0  0  0",   header=TRUE)
and I get  In res[up] <- unlist(DF[i, -1]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: @ Roland: Should I repost what result I get when I use several comaprisons ? Am unable to figure out where am going wrong !

Comment: @user2294316 I'll have a look later. I'm at work right now.

Comment: @user2294316 But have you adjusted `m_temp` to have enough rows and collumns?

Comment: @ Roland : Thanks. Yes, I did adjust that but it seems to change the values in the fourth column. I checked it several times.

Comment: The data you gave is missing D-E. You could change my solution to check for missing combinations, but that would need some additional parsing of column names and I leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks. yes my original data has some combinations missing.

Comment: @ Roland: Iam sorry but I guess there is a bug in the script somewhere because even after including the missing combination several values in the corresponding matrices are filled at random and do not contribute to original values. I rechecked again :( If you see the matrix is no longer the mirror image in the upper and lower part :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33708/discussion-between-user2294316-and-roland)